# Moduled project not compiling using lombok

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, lombok

I'm making a project using lombok. The structur of it is:

**Main project:**

- **module A**
- **module B**
- **module C**

I created a main function in **module A** to test the program.

Module A depends on module B and C, module B on anything and module C on module A and B (don't know if this is important to know).

When I run the main function on module A it gives me an error:

```
Error:java: Annotation processing is not supported for module cycles. Please ensure that all modules from cycle [A,B,C] are excluded from annotation processing
```

I think it is caused by lombok. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Anyone?  *Bump****

Comment: Where do the modules come from? Maven modules or jdk9? The error message is quite clear; whatever compile tool you are currently using, it doesn't support annotationprocessors.